# Python: Killing children's children process

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, signals, kill

I have a process that calls:

```
p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func_a)
```

Then `func_a` starts a subprocess:

```
subprocess.Popen(["nc", "-l", "-p", str(dport)], stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"))
```

My problem is that when I call `p.terminate()`, it only kills the first child. `p.terminate()` is a `SIGKILL` so how could I make the subprocess die when I call `p.terminate()` into the `multiprocessing.Process`.

Comment: According to [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate), `p.terminate()` sends `SIGTERM`, whereas `SIGKILL` is sent by `p.kill()`

Answer (score 1):

Register a handler with signal.signal like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        #iterate over your subprocess and kill them
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal."the signal", signal_handler)
print('Press Ctrl+C')
signal.pause()
```

More documentation on signal can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html).

Comment: I think SIGKILL can not be captured: 

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

Comment: You're right, my bad I'll set the answer just with a generic signal handler

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to **make sure the sub-process is killed before the multiprocessing process is killed**:

Create a class like this:

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyProcess,self).__init__()
        self.q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def run(self):
        # do something else
        child = subprocess.Popen(['Your CMD'])
        self.q.put(child.pid)

    def MyTerminate(self):
        pid = self.q.get()
        os.kill(pid, 9) # works in windows and linux
        # os.popen('taskkill.exe /pid '+str(pid)+' /F') # works only in windows
        self.terminate()
```

Then you can use the function `MyTerminate()` to kill the process safely.

For example:

```
def main():
    mp = MyProcess()
    mp.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    mp.MyTerminate()
```

The sub-process "child" will be killed after 1 second.

Comment: ah nice!! I thought about that, but I did not wanted to add a queue to the whole thing. What would happen if the child fails to create the subprocess and then nothing is queued? Upon calling `MyTerminate` we would block the program, right? Should we add a timeout of 1 second ?

Comment: @edgarcosta - You may use try/except to put a `False` into queue when creating subprocess failed, and then use a `if pid:` before `os.kill(pid,9)`. In fact, I don't want to use queue, but we have to find a way to transport pid to `MyTerminate()`. In my test, member variables dont work in `run()`. So multiprocessing.Queue is an effective way to do that work.  As for timeout, I think the `time.sleep(1)` in main() works like some kind of timeout.